# ¿Cómo cambiar con un botón siguiente las tabs de las clases de bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                                       <a id="btnsiguiente" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile">Siguiente</a>

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">2</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">3</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Me encontré con un problema y no logro solucionarlo, lo que quiero realizar es agregar un botón "siguiente" dentro de un `div`, con la clase `tab-pane`.

Tomando el ejemplo que está en la documentación de Bootstrap, hice lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
       <a id="btnsiguiente" class="btn btn-primary" href="#profile">Siguiente</a>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      Mensaje despues de presionar el boton siguiente
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">

  </div>
</div>
```

Explico con mejor detalle:

Lo que hice fue que en la clase dentro del div `tab-pane` agregué un botón, con el fin de meter un formulario, luego de terminar de llenar el formulario, presionar o hacer click a un botón y me muestre el siguiente panel, pero no lo hace. ¿A que se deberá esto?

Esto fue lo que agregué como una simple muestra pero no lo hace, en el `href="#profile"` indiqué que hiciera referencia al siguiente panel, ¿cómo podría solucionar este problema?

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
       <a id="btnsiguiente" class="btn btn-primary" href="#profile">Siguiente</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: yo lo haria al div para que me abra el div , ya lo intentaste ?

Comment: Creo que no entendí muy bien

Comment: mira abajo te deje un ejemplo con puro HTML el cual lo podras usar en tu codigo con boostrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edicion: No habia notado que la pregunta es de 2018

Segun entiendo quieres que al hacer click se avance en los tabs o pills de BS, con las clases y funciones solamente de Bootstrap no es posible, pero puedes hacer tu propio script y agregar la funcion con JavaScript.

Por ejemplo agregando una clase para agrupar los pills de navegacion, seleccionandolos y luego agregando una funcion al evento click de "Siguiente" para que simule el click en cada uno los pills de navegacion.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".left-tabs a");

    let nextTab = document.getElementById("v-pills-next-tab");

    let i = 0;

    nextTab.addEventListener("click", function() {

        i = (i == (tabs.length - 1)) ? 0 : i + 1;
        tabs[i].click();

    }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills left-tabs" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
         <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="h-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-next-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Siguiente</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">Contenido de Home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">Contenido de Profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab"> Contenido de Messages</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab"> Contenido de Settings</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas es algo así:

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#welcome">Welcome</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="welcome">Welcome to this website</div>
<div id="about">About this website, and such</div>
<div id="section3">The third section</div>
```

Sólo lo puedes adaptar a tu código y listo.

Comment: Si es lo que intento hacer, justo es lo que esta en el ejemplo pero no funciona, supongo que tiene que ver por las clases que estan en el div, pero no se si existe otra forma de cambiar de panel al hacer clic en el boton siguiente

Comment: no tiene nada que ver con class :p mira comparte todo tu codigo junto a los css y JS creo que tu error esta ahi

Comment: en esta parte quitale el "-tab" y solo deja "profile", porque? porque a ese ID hacer referencia y como recuerdas este simbolo # siginifica los ID https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a> <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fLg75anj/ a ver aqui lo comparto. lo intente como dices y no paso nada